# Changing view controllers on rotation to a single common view controller objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok, so I'm working on an objective-c ios app here where I have multiple portrait view controllers. I don't however want any of these view controllers to display in landscape, instead what I want to happen is for a single landscape view controller to segue in when the device is rotated to landscape and segue out again to a specific view controller when rotated back to portrait. This isn't just a case of resizing an exisiting view, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I'd start this way: Listen for orientation changes...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
```

Upon change to landscape, present a landscape vc.  Upon change to portrait, dismiss it...

```
- (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) && self.presentedViewController) {
        [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) && !self.presentedViewController) {
        MyLandscapeVC *landscapeVC = [[MyLandscapeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyLandscapeVC" bundle:nil];  // or however you make this
        [self presentViewController:landscapeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The extra check for `self.presentedViewController` is to guard against any sloppiness in the system during quick rotations back and forth, so we never get more than one of the landscape vcs stacked up. It may be unnecessary.

This can be isolated in one file using a class category on UIViewController, like this...

```
// in UIViewController+Rotations.h

@interface UIViewController (Rotations)
- (void)observeRotations;
@end

// in UIViewController+Rotations.m

#import "UIViewController+Rotations.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Rotations)

- (void)observeRotations {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // etc., from above
}

@end
```

Just import UIViewController+Rotations.h in your view controllers, and early in the lifecycle (probably viewWillAppear) call `[self observeRotations];`

Comment: Well now it crashes when it orientates, that at least means that the method is being called, ill just have to work out a better method to call the next view controller. thanks.

Comment: Yay it works now!! I just changed a bit of the code you gave me handeling the segue to this:  - 
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) && !self.presentedViewController) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"flowJump" sender:self];

    }
}

Comment: I made a manuel segue in the storyboard and called that, works a charm, all that remains is to scale things properly.

Comment: @Jobalisk - glad it works, and yes, building the landscape vc from a nib will crash if there's no nib.  That code (along with the comment) was meant to indicate that you need to substitute a vc setup that matches how your vc is defined.